# .CPP file from folder reference linking error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to add Boost open source code into my iOS app by adding boost as reference folder. Boost has many sub folders with .hpp and .cpp files inside that. But I am not able to build due to link error 'boost/algorithm/string.hpp' file not found. I added header path in User HeaderPath like : "$(projectpath)/boost/". Even I tried putting in search header path. Set flag "YES". I tried put files in build compose but only directory added. But error saying file not found. So Can some one suggest how to handle this situation and remove link error and run app successfully.. If two different open source libraries available then how to achieve this also. Kindly help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should probably pre-build boost as a static lib and use it that way, as I highly doubt you will be modifying boost.

Your problem is most likely how you are using Header Search Paths.

You do not use `-I`. Xcode will implicitly put it in there for you. The path is relative to the location of the `.xcodeproj` folder. So it should be based on that. In the short-term, if you need you could absolute path it as a test. But using relative path is best.

Additionally, you may need to make the search recursive. User Header Search Paths has same syntax. To do what you want, you should only need Header Search Path.